# Can't position two elements with the same class correctly after adding them as buttons that open modals

Tags: html, css

so I'm working on making a small one-page Kiosk type page and when I went to add the buttons and modals that are key to making the page work, two of the div elements that use the same classes get displaced. Here is a pastebin link to the code which contains the CSS, HTML, and JS for the page: https://pastebin.com/MqVHkyCW

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: roboto;
        src: url(fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: bebasneue;
        src: url(fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf);
}
body {
    font-family: "bebasneue";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #0c0f15;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.heading-page {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 43px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: white;
}
a {
    color: inherit;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: #ababab;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0 none;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

/*
 * Selection color
 */
::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #fa6862;
    color: #fff;
}

::selection {
    background-color: #fa6862;
    color: #fff;
}

/*
 *  Reset bootstrap's default style
 */
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder,
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
    color: inherit;
}

.form-control:-moz-placeholder,
:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    opacity: 1;
    color: inherit;
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder,
::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    opacity: 1;
    color: inherit;
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder,
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
    color: inherit;
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea,
label {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.btn {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
}

.btn-primary {
    background-color: #fa6862;
    border: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 42px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:active:focus {
    background-color: #f9423a;
}

.btn-border {
    border: 1px solid #d7d8db;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
}

/*
 *  CSS Helper Class
 */
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}

.pt-table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 4px);
    height: -moz-calc(100vh - 4px);
    height: calc(100vh - 4px);
}

.pt-tablecell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.primary,
.link:hover {
    color: #fa6862;
}

.no-gutter {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.no-gutter > [class^="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-middle {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.space-between {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -moz-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.preloader {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.preloader.active.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.loading-mask {
    background-color: #fa6862;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 20%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.61, 0, 0.6, 1) 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.61, 0, 0.6, 1) 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.61, 0, 0.6, 1) 0s;
    transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.61, 0, 0.6, 1) 0s;
}
.loading-mask:nth-child(2) {
    left: 20%;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.loading-mask:nth-child(3) {
    left: 40%;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.loading-mask:nth-child(4) {
    left: 60%;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.loading-mask:nth-child(5) {
    left: 80%;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.preloader.active.done {
    z-index: 0;
}

.preloader.active .loading-mask {
    width: 0;
}

/*------------------------------------------------
    Start Styling
-------------------------------------------------*/
img#logo {
    max-width: 50rem;
}

.mt20 {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-left: 0%;
    padding-top: 100%;
}

.page-close {
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.page-title {
    margin-bottom: 75px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #db3623;
    width: 100%;
}
.page-title img {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 2.5rem;
}
.page-title h2 {
    font-size: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.page-title p {
    font-size: 72px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
}
.page-title .title-bg {
    color: rgba(30, 37, 48, 0.07);
    font-size: 158px;
    left: 0;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    line-height: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.section-title {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.section-title h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.section-title h3::before,
.section-title h3::after {
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: -webkit-calc(100% + 14px);
    left: -moz-calc(100% + 14px);
    left: calc(100% + 14px);
}
.section-title h3::before {
    background-color: #1e2530;
    width: 96px;
    bottom: 14px;
}
.section-title h3::after {
    background-color: #fa6862;
    width: 73px;
}
.section-title.light h3 {
    color: #fff;
}
.section-title.light h3::before {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.page-nav {
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.page-nav span {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    line-height: 0.9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*------------------------------------------------
    Home Page
-------------------------------------------------*/

.hexagon-item:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.page-home {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.page-home .overlay {
    background-color: rgba(14, 17, 24, 0.97);
    z-index: -1;
}

/* End of container */
.hexagon-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 200px;
    height: 173.20508px;
    margin-left: -29px;
    z-index: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.hexagon-item:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.hexagon-item:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}
.hexagon-item:hover .hex-item:last-child {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    -o-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
.hexagon-item:hover .hex-item:first-child {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.hexagon-item:hover .hex-item:first-child div:before,
.hexagon-item:hover .hex-item:first-child div:after {
    height: 5px;
}
.hexagon-item:hover .hex-item div::before,
.hexagon-item:hover .hex-item div::after {
    background-color: #db3623;
}
.hexagon-item:hover .hex-content svg {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.97);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.97);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.97);
    -o-transform: scale(0.97);
    transform: scale(0.97);
}

.page-home .hexagon-item:nth-last-child(1),
.page-home .hexagon-item:nth-last-child(2),
.page-home .hexagon-item:nth-last-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(87px, -80px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(87px, -80px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(87px, -80px);
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(87px, -80px);
    transform: rotate(30deg) translate(87px, -80px);
}

.hex-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 173.20508px;
}
.hex-item:first-child {
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
    -o-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
.hex-item:last-child {
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
    z-index: 1;
}
.hex-item div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 173.20508px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -moz-transform-origin: center center;
    -ms-transform-origin: center center;
    -o-transform-origin: center center;
    transform-origin: center center;
}
.hex-item div::before,
.hex-item div::after {
    background-color: #1e2530;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0s;
}
.hex-item div:before {
    top: 0;
}
.hex-item div:after {
    bottom: 0;
}
.hex-item div:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%);
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%);
}
.hex-item div:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-50%);
    transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-50%);
}
.hex-item div:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg) translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) translate(-50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(120deg) translate(-50%);
    transform: rotate(120deg) translate(-50%);
}

.hex-content {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    width: 156px;
}
.hex-content .hex-content-inner {
    left: 50%;
    margin: -3px 0 0 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hex-content .icon {
    display: block;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}
.hex-content .title {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "bebasneue";
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.hex-content svg {
    left: -7px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    transform: scale(0.87);
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0s;
}
.hex-content:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.page-home .hexagon-item:nth-last-child(1),
.page-home .hexagon-item:nth-last-child(2),
.page-home .hexagon-item:nth-last-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%) rotate(30deg) translate(87px, -80px);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%) rotate(30deg) translate(87px, -80px);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%) rotate(30deg) translate(87px, -80px);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%) rotate(30deg) translate(87px, -80px);
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(30deg) translate(87px, -80px) ;
}
/*------------------------------------------------
    Welcome Page
-------------------------------------------------*/
.author-image-large {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.author-image-large img {
    height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 4px);
    height: -moz-calc(100vh - 4px);
    height: calc(100vh - 4px);
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66666667%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%;
    }
}

.hexagon-item:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.pt-table.desktop-768 .pt-tablecell {
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.hexagon-item:hover .icon i {
    color: #db3623;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.hexagon-item:hover .title {
    -webkit-animation: focus-in-contract 0.5s
        cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
    animation: focus-in-contract 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}
/***************************/

@-webkit-keyframes focus-in-contract {
    0% {
        letter-spacing: 1em;
        -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
        filter: blur(12px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
        filter: blur(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes focus-in-contract {
    0% {
        letter-spacing: 1em;
        -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
        filter: blur(12px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
        filter: blur(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .hexagon-item {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto 50px;
    }
    .hexagon-item:first-child {
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    .page-home .hexagon-item:nth-last-child(1),
    .page-home .hexagon-item:nth-last-child(2),
    .page-home .hexagon-item:nth-last-child(3) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(0px, 0px);
        -moz-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(0px, 0px);
        -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(0px, 0px);
        -o-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: rotate(30deg) translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}

.price {
    padding-right: 2.5%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    text-align: right;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 50%;
}

.btn:active {
}

.close-modal {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.modal {
    width: 450px;
    position: fixed;
    top: -50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.modal.active {
    top: 15%;
}

.modal .header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.modal .body {
    padding: 0.75rem;
}

#overlaymodal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#overlaymodal.active {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<main class="site-wrapper">
<div class="pt-table desktop-768">
    <div class="pt-tablecell page-home relative" style="background-image: 
url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486870591958-9b9d0d1dda99?ixlib=rb- 
1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80);
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="centerdiv">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="page-title  home text-center">
                            <span class="heading-page"></span>
                            <img src="logo.png" id="logo">
                            <p class="mt20"> Panasonic Toughbook CF-31 </p> <h2 class="price"> 
Starting at $499.25! </h2>
                        </div>
                    <br style="clear: both;">
                    <div class="hexagon-menu clear">
                            <div class="hexagon-item">
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="hex-content">
                                    <button class="btn" data-target="#modal1">
                                    <span class="hex-content-inner">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <i class="specifications"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="title">SPECIFICATIONS</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 173.20508075688772 200" height="200" 
width="174" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path d="M86.60254037844386 0L173.20508075688772 
50L173.20508075688772 150L86.60254037844386 200L0 150L0 50Z" fill="#1e2530"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                                <div class="modal" id="modal1">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <div class="title">First Modal</div>
                                        <button class="btn close-modal">&times;</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modalbody">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="hexagon-item">
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="hex-content">
                                    <button class="btn" data-target="#modal2">
                                    <span class="hex-content-inner">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <i class="models"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="title">Models</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 173.20508075688772 200" height="200" 
width="174" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path d="M86.60254037844386 0L173.20508075688772 
50L173.20508075688772 150L86.60254037844386 200L0 150L0 50Z" fill="#1e2530"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                                <div class="modal" id="modal2">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <div class="title">First Modal</div>
                                        <button class="btn close-modal">&times;</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modalbody">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="hexagon-item">
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="hex-content">
                                    <button class="btn" data-target="#modal3">
                                    <span class="hex-content-inner">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <i class="upgrades"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="title">Upgrades</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 173.20508075688772 200" height="200" 
width="174" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path d="M86.60254037844386 0L173.20508075688772 
50L173.20508075688772 150L86.60254037844386 200L0 150L0 50Z" fill="#1e2530"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                                <div class="modal" id="modal3">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <div class="title">First Modal</div>
                                        <button class="btn close-modal">&times;</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modalbody">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="hexagon-item">
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="hex-content">
                                    <button class="btn" data-target="#modal4">
                                    <span class="hex-content-inner">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <i class="warranty"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="title">Warranty</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 173.20508075688772 200" height="200" 
 width="174" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path d="M86.60254037844386 0L173.20508075688772 
 50L173.20508075688772 150L86.60254037844386 200L0 150L0 50Z" fill="#1e2530"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                                <div class="modal" id="modal4">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <div class="title">First Modal</div>
                                        <button class="btn close-modal">&times;</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modalbody">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                            <div class="hexagon-item">
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="hex-content">
                                    <button class="btn" data-target="#modal5">
                                    <span class="hex-content-inner">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <i class="repair"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="title">Repairs and Service</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 173.20508075688772 200" height="200" 
width="174" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path d="M86.60254037844386 0L173.20508075688772 
50L173.20508075688772 150L86.60254037844386 200L0 150L0 50Z" fill="#1e2530"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                                <div class="modal" id="modal5">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <div class="title">First Modal</div>
                                        <button class="btn close-modal">&times;</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modalbody">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="hexagon-item">
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="hex-content">
                                    <button class="btn" data-target="#modal6">
                                    <span class="hex-content-inner">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <i class="placeholder"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="title">Placeholder</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 173.20508075688772 200" height="200" 
width="174" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path d="M86.60254037844386 0L173.20508075688772 
50L173.20508075688772 150L86.60254037844386 200L0 150L0 50Z" fill="#1e2530"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                                <div class="modal" id="modal6">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <div class="title">First Modal</div>
                                        <button class="btn close-modal">&times;</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modalbody">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="hexagon-item">
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hex-item">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="hex-content">
                                    <button class="btn" data-target="#modal7">
                                    <span class="hex-content-inner">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <i class="contact"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="title">Contact Us</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 173.20508075688772 200" height="200" 
width="174" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path d="M86.60254037844386 0L173.20508075688772 
50L173.20508075688772 150L86.60254037844386 200L0 150L0 50Z" fill="#1e2530"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                                <div class="modal" id="modal7">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <div class="title">First Modal</div>
                                        <button class="btn close-modal">&times;</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modalbody">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="overlaymodal"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The hexagons are supposed to look like this: https://gyazo.com/fefecd37b6aa60369e89bd4d9312ccb5

Mine look like this: https://gyazo.com/8e1f016aafc33e2e2acfcc80ddcbe88b

I'm looking to get the two hexagons that are not in the "honeycomb" to sit nicely along with the other 5 hexagons. Before I added the buttons and modals, everything sat perfectly in the page.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I attempted to create a demo snippet out of your code, but you've posted more than the 30,000 allowed characters (after formatting). That seems excessive. Please see [ask], then provide a _minimal_ example in a working snippet demo.

Comment: Protip: You don't need most of those vendor prefixes. See https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition, for example. That cuts a few hundred lines right there.